# how many hops does it take?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-traversal

Im searching for information on an experiment where it was determined how many hops it would take  for a message to theoretically reach everyone on  Earth (i.e. 8 billion). So if every reciever would  forward the messae to  X  contacts, it would take Y hops to reach the earths population. I only  can remember that Y was  suprisingly low,  and X was not high either.

Can any help me with the name of the experiment or any more information?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical mathematics.

Comment: You might have better chance finding info here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this Wikipedia article about the six degrees of separation will answer your question:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful information! :-)